# Term for when speakers of L1, over time, pronounce words in their language like phonetically similar words found in the more dominant L2?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics

I am looking for the name of the following phenomenon:

1. Speakers of Language 1 transplant a given word to a new environment in which Language 2 is the dominant language spoken in the area.
2. Language 2 has a word that is *phonetically similar* to a word found in Language 1 - though with a completely different meaning.
3. With continued exposure to the dominant Language 2 - speakers of Language 1 alter their pronunciation of their native word and begin to pronounce the relevant native word identically to the *phonetically* similar word that they were exposed to in the dominant Language 2 - *while retaining the original meaning found in Language 1*.

Is there a particular name for this phenomenon? This seems to be Phonetic Interference, but what kind of Interference is this? I am looking, specifically, for the name of this particular phenomenon. All of my books mention this phenomenon, but do not give it a name for some reason. What exactly is it called?

Comment: If it's about a change in pronunciation of _just one particular_ word and it affects _all_ or a substantial part of Language A speakers, then it is a kind of _borrowing_. “Interference” is a term which is usually used when talking about L2 acquisition when L1 affects one's L2 skills, but in your case the direction is reversed, it's not interference (or maybe it is, but then it's interference in some _very_ wide sense).

Comment: I'm interested in something that explains when acquisition of L2 affects one's pronunciation of words retained from L1 in such a way that words retained from L1 among a particular population are now pronounced like similar forms (though with vastly different meanings) found in L2. Is there any literature on this topic? Is there an actual name for this phenomenon, or is this something that has not yet been studied (which I find  hard to believe)?? Please help.

Comment: Did you consider the _strata_ phenomena? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratum_(linguistics) If your languages A and B continue to co-exist, then they are in _adstratum_ relationship. If B finally suppresses A, then A is _substratum_ and B is _superstratum_.

Comment: I have heard of the strata phenomena, but have some confusion about the uses (or contexts for usage) of the terms substratum and superstratum. If Language A is suppressed by Language B, but former speakers of Language A *retain some words* from Language A, are those retained words referred to as substratum?

Comment: That's right, the retained words of a suppressed language are substratum.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback! EDIT: My texbook says that substrate refers to a linguistic variety that "has influenced the structure or use of a more dominant variety. If the retentions are words only and not syntax, how is the language still a substrate?

Answer (score 1):

On the individual level, there is the well-known phenomenon of **Phonetic accommodation** when two speakers in a dialogue tend to converge phonetically.

I would consider this kind of levelling still as an accommodation process (caused by a superstrate language, as @Yellow Sky has noted in a comment to the question).

Comment: Would this kind of levelling still be an accommodation process if Language A is finally suppressed by Language B, while former speakers of Language A retain words only from Language A?

Comment: I don't understand your additional question. When the language A is suppressed, why should former speakers of A only retain words of A? Do you mean they retain only some words [note the position of only] of language A? In that case, we change the perspective and talk of an A-substrate in language B.

Comment: _"Do you mean they retain only some words [note the position of only]"_   Yes, that's what I mean, pardon. I thought that "substrate" only referred to the syntax of a given language - and that if grammar is not retained, then there is no substrate. Is this untrue?

Comment: *Strata* can affect anything in a language: Phonemes, vocabulary, idioms, derivation and inflection, syntax, there is no restriction here.